# How to remove symbols from the string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a format of date as follows. I want to remove the / from starting and from the last how can I remove and get the date in my case currently I am getting like /2018-09-09/

```
/2018-07-19/
```

I want to remove the / from starting and from the last. How can I remove and get the date in my case. Currently I am getting like /2018-09-09/ but I want that 2018-09-09 only. I am a beginner in jQuery and JavaScript.

Comment: Please show us, what did you trying to do to achieve your goal. Probably you should use the regex.

Comment: well you should've told us that this is NOT a string, but a date :)

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Regex `/\//g` (escaping the slash) with `replace()`:

```js
var str = '/2018-07-19/'
str = str.replace(/\//g,'')
console.log(str);
```

Comment: i tried this but its returning me the error like:   str = evnt_date.replace(/\//g,'')
     alert(str);
     TypeError: evnt_date.replace is not a function[Learn More]

Comment: @Apoorva, that means `evnt_date` is not a string......is it a date?

Comment: yes its a date........................

Comment: @Apoorva, can you make that as a string like `evnt_date.toString().replace(..` ...

Comment: tthanx its working now @mamun

Comment: @Apoorva, you are most welcome. Glad to hear that :)

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to do this. One is using `split()` then `join()`

```js
let str = '/2018-07-19/'
str = str.split('/').join('')
console.log(str)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: i tried this but its returning me the error like:                    
     str = evnt_date.split('/').join('');
      console.log(str);
      TypeError: evnt_date.split is not a function[Learn More]

Comment: @Apoorva then maybe your `evnt_date` is not string. By the way, declare your variables in javaScript with camelCase not underscore. so `evntDate`. Try `console.log(typeof evnt_date)` or `console.log(typeof evntDate)` if you change your variable name. And tell me here what you get in the console.

Comment: i didi and get str = evntDate.split('/').join('')
     console.log(typeof str);
     TypeError: evntDate.split is not a function[Learn More]

Comment: @Aporova no. Just do `console.log(typeof evntDate)` without any other code

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
  var ret = "/2018-09-09/".replace('/','');
```

Comment: this only replaces the first occurrence of the '/' character

Comment: i tried this but its returning me the error  var ret = evnt_date.replace('/','');
      alert(ret);

      TypeError: evnt_dates.replace is not a function[Learn More]

Comment: That's because `evnt_date` is not a string. From the context of the variable name I would assume it's a Date object